# Rad Upload modification

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, upload, telerik

i have a Rad Upload control to upload more than one image ,,the problem is

::

i want each image to have a caption (inserted by the user as a text)during the uploading operation,,
so what i wanna to do is modifying the  Rad Upload control and adding a text box in it and access the data in this text box .. how to do this????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if there is a GOOD way to modify the RadUpload control.
I think most appropriate solution would be to create a user control containing the RadUpload and text field.

EDIT:
I checked the documentation that it is possible to add custom fields with javascript. See an example on this page:
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/upload_raduploadaddinginformation.html

and a live demo here:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/upload/examples/additionalfields/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: i tried to think in this idea ,, but the Rad upload has a great feature ,,it has a button to add new Rad upload for uploading more images ,,if i do what u said ,then i have to create many Rad controls on the fly and disable this button..

Comment: really. I did not think this problem. I found a solution, in EDIT of this answer.